# Error 400 on trying to add a contact in mailchimp

Tags: node.js, express, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am getting this error when trying to call the mailchimp API V3 to add a new contact to my list

```
"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the \'errors\' array.","instance":"f8b79d9b-1c02-4062-a0e4-847e31f7bd61","errors":[{"field":"","message":"Schema describes object, NULL found instead"}]}'
```

Here is the code used:

```
app.post("/", function(req,res){
var email = req.body.email;

var data = {
    members : [
        {
            email_address: email,
            status: "subscribed"
        }
    ]
};

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

var options = {
    headers :{
        'Authorization': 'thomas APIKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': jsonData.length
    },
    url: "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists",
    method: "POST",
    data:jsonData
};

console.log(options);

request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else{
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

I tried adding **/Listkey/members** to my url with no success

Do you have some tips? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the elements passed to request were not good.
Here is the functional code:

```
app.post("/", function(req,res){
  var email = req.body.email;

  var data = {
    "email_address": email,
    "status" : "subscribed"
  };


  var options = {
    "url": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/c9b9a6e109/members/",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "thomas APIKEY"
    },
    "body": data,
    "json": true
  };
})
```